# Map bonus quests aren't completing

Tags: path-of-exile

I've already completed the bonus quest (killing the boss) on two maps Atoll and Ramparts. On both Channel and Flooded Mine I do have the bonus quest completed:
[image]
When I play on Atoll or Ramparts I don't get the boss kill mission, suggesting it has already been completed.
[image]
I fully completed the Atoll map three times, once with a bestiary event. What's going wrong here? I'd like to get the benefits from the atlas bonus quest completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the map modifiers (only 1% quantity) means you're running a normal version of the map as opposed to magic or rare. You won't complete the bonus objective unless it is done at a certain rarity depending on the tier of the map. To make it magic just use an orb of transmute on any normal map. Maps can be crafted with the same orbs as weapons and armor. If you get map mods that you don't like you can reroll them to get something more desirable.

If you open up the Atlas and hover a map it will show you this box seen below with the bonus objective. In the case of tier 1-5 (white maps) it is completing the map while it is at least a magic rarity. Tier 6-10 (yellow) require completing at least a rare version, and tiers 11-16 (red) require rare corrupted maps. Once done you get the checkmark and the yellow ring you see around your channel and flooded mine.

[image: map bonus example]